# K-Map Reduction Grouping Question

Tags: computer-architecture, karnaugh-map

I have a simple question regarding reduction using K-Maps.

My professor gave this example:

[image: example given by professor]

While I somewhat understand that we can only group quantities of base 2 numbers, why did my professor group the K-Map values like the image above instead of the image below (what I drafted):

[image: k-map that I drafted]

Why did my professor include elements 0 & 1? Why not just a group of 2 consisting of elements 4 & 5?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, what motivation is there to group minterms in the first place?

Comment: To reduce to simpler boolean logic?

Comment: There is that. So what do the terms for the groups you presented look like, which one is shorter/simpler?

Comment: Oh I see. So what I grouped together is X' + XY', which is more complicated. I understand now. Thank you greybeard for all your help.